# C# How to solve Web Client Upload file "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed."? 

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, file-upload, upload, geoserver

Hello I want to upload a html file that is in my local to a remote folder in a server that contains a data dir with geoserver elements, and here is my code:

```
public void CopyWS(string SourcePath, string DestinationPath)
    {
        try
        {

            string SourcePath = Path.GetFullPath("Result.html");
            string DestinationPath = @"http://xx.xx.xxx.:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/";               
            string authInfo = "admin:geoserver";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(authInfo));

          client.UploadFile(DestinationPath, "PUT", SourcePath); 
}

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }
```

I´m getting the following error "Error 405 method not allowed". I´m trying with different methods like **post** instead of **put** but I´m getting the same error.

**EDIT:** Anybody think that maybe can be a security problem? With UploadData I´m getting the same error

**EDIT:** After a long time testing with different methods (UploadDatat i.e) I´m getting always the same error.I've been searching and reading around to that and couldn't fine anything really useful.

**EDIT:** Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does the contents of `DestinationPath` look like?

Comment: Basically Method Not Allowed means that the PUT verb is not configured

Answer (score 1):

`PUT` is not configured... usually `PUT` (but not always) means that the server understands `WebDAV`... `HTTP` uploads are usually done via `POST`...

another possibility would be that some proxy blocks `PUT`.

EDIT - as per comment:

POST requests need to the be built differentley and depends on how the server expects them... for some sample code see [Upload files with HTTPWebrequest (multipart/form-data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566462/upload-files-with-httpwebrequest-multipart-form-data/567460#567460)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Yahia but with POST I´m getting Error 400 Bad Request

Comment: In your example they are using HTTPWebrequest is not possible with WebClient?

Comment: you can try `client.UploadFile(DestinationPath, SourcePath);` BUT as in my EDIT the server might expect some specific things in a `POST` and then you better use HTTPWebRequest...

Comment: Thanks  I´m finishing with my tests about Web Client and I will start with HTTPWebrequest I thougth that with WebClient was possible but now I´m not sure