# error: (405) Method Not Allowed when uploading file to https

Tags: c#, file-upload, https

Wrote a code to upload file to a https folder as below

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            string webAddress = null;
            try
            {
                webAddress = @"https://www.example.net/mydocs";
                webClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                webClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

                WebRequest serverRequest = WebRequest.Create(webAddress);
                WebResponse serverResponse;
                serverResponse = serverRequest.GetResponse();
                serverResponse.Close();

                webClient.UploadFile(webAddress , "PUT", @"C:\d\1.xml");
                webClient.Dispose();
                webClient = null;
            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(error.Message);
            }
```

the line `webClient.UploadFile(webAddress , "PUT", @"C:\d\1.xml");`
returning an error

> The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.

Comment: Does your website where you are uploading files allows the Verb `PUT` ?

Comment: I've seen this error while accessing my services in the past. it has mostly to do with securities or rights. better is to check eventlog to get the exact reason of it. otherwise, restart the app pool and check if that works or not

Comment: @Sachu,Does NTLM is supported?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7024523/c-sharp-how-to-solve-web-client-upload-file-the-remote-server-returned-an-error

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10134632/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-405-method-not-allowed-wcf-rest-service .. Also make sure you have write permisson on the same folder where you are uploading

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the method `PUT` is not supported on the server. Make sure it's the correct method supported. You can try with `POST`

```
 webClient.UploadFile(webAddress , "POST", @"C:\d\1.xml");
```

Comment: I changed the Method from "PUT" to "POST" but still, I am getting the same error in MVC.